# App-routing works in web build but not working in cordova build

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I'm working on converting angular to cordova for mobile apps and for the routing, I have a menu which contains link to go to a different page. this link works in the web build but not in the cordova build. I've tried the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   // routes set up
 }
]

export const UsersRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'});

            {url:'./home', text: 'Home', path: 'home'},
            {url:'/', text: 'Home2', path: 'home'},
            {url:'./', text: 'Home3', path: 'home'},
            {url:'./home', text: 'Home4'},
            {url:'/', text: 'Home5'},
            {url:'./', text: 'Home6'},
            {text: 'Home7', path: 'home'},
            {text: 'Home8', path: ''},
            {text: 'Home9', path: '/'},
            {text: 'Home10', component: HomeComponent}
```

I have the home path set up as

```
 {
path: 'home',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

and another with path ''.

```
 {
path: '',
// more content
},
```

None of these work for cordova build, but they all do for the web build. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to use `hashbang` setting? What settings are you using when you new up the `Router` object?

Comment: @hvaughn3 I edited the code so you have an idea how mine is set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I tried to print the url when the app was built in cordova and it gave a file url (file://link-to-the-app) so I used this instead:

```
{text: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'center', url: window.location.href}
```

and that worked perfectly